# Nothing being added to generic List<string> Add method

Tags: c#, asp.net

Code for Property in JobQuote class:

```
 public class JobQuote
{
// Properties
private List<string> _jobfilenames;
public List<string> JobFileNames
{
    get
    {
        if (_jobfilenames != null)
            return _jobfilenames;
        else
        {
            _jobfilenames = new List<string>();
            return _jobfilenames;
        }
    }

    set { _jobfilenames = value; }
}
```

Code for Property in User Control

```
public JobQuote quote
{
    get 
    {
        if (ViewState["Quote"] != null)
            return (JobQuote)ViewState["Quote"];
        else
        {
            JobQuote newQuote = new JobQuote();
            return newQuote;
        }   
    }
    set { ViewState["Quote"] = value; }
}
```

Code in try block of UserControl where the string is not being added to the generic list of strings:

```
try
        {
            string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUploader.FileName);
            quote.JobFileNames.Add(filename); 
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what's going on?

Comment: No, there is no Exception occurring within the code I have shown here. One is thrown later, however, stating that "Sequence contains no elements".

Comment: What is the value of `filename` when it's passed to `Add()`?

Comment: When I step through the code I can see that nothing is being added to the list when the Add method is called.

Comment: The value of filename is whatever the name of the file that I upload is. So yes, it does contain a value when passed to the Add method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reading from the viewstate but you never assign.

```
public JobQuote quote 
{ 
    get  
    { 
        if (ViewState["Quote"] != null) 
            return (JobQuote)ViewState["Quote"]; 
        else 
        { 
            // you only construct a new instance but you dont assign it to the viewstate
            JobQuote newQuote = new JobQuote(); 
            // add the following line to fix the problem
            // ViewState["Quote"] = newQuote;
            return newQuote; 
        }    
    }
```

This means that next time you refer to the quote property, a new JobQuote instance will be created rather than your old JobQuote instance being returned

A clean way for implementing this would be:

```
public JobQuote Quote
{
    get
    {
        JobQuote result = ViewState["Quote"] as JobQuote;
        if (result == null)
        {
            result = new JobQuote();
            ViewState["Quote"] = result;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: while it is not being set in the setter, view state is being set in the getter for quote

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a new `JobQuote` instance every time. Try this:

```
public JobQuote quote
{
    get 
    {
        if (ViewState["Quote"] != null)
            return (JobQuote)ViewState["Quote"];
        else
        {
            JobQuote newQuote = new JobQuote();
            ViewState["Quote"] = newQuote;
            return newQuote;
        }   
    }
    set { ViewState["Quote"] = value; }
}
```

or:

```
public JobQuote quote
{
    get 
    {
        if (ViewState["Quote"] == null)
            ViewState["Quote"] = new JobQuote();

        return (JobQuote)ViewState["Quote"];
    }
    set { ViewState["Quote"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: I prefer the 2nd way for 2 reasons : 1- It's shorter, neater. 2- Your get only has one return, which is usually a good practice afaik.

Comment: @Tipx Yep. I prefer it that way too. Easier to read and understand IMO.